# How to get sum of amount before every monday in weekly wise report in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I created a report where I have to show previous balance weekly wise for one financial year.

I have two tables:

1) Sales

```
Sales_Id    int
Quantity    decimal
Rate    numeric
Sale_Amount numeric
Sale_Agent  varchar
```

2) Payment

```
Payement_id int
Agent_Id    varchar
Amount  numeric
Received_Date   smalldatetime
```

In sale table, sale amount column for every customer and in payment table, amount column for payment_received for customer. So I am minus payment received amount from sale amount **(sales_amount-amount)** every weekly. A week is from Monday to Sunday. So before every Monday, I have to subtract (Sum(sales_amount)-sum(amount)).

So I am trying the query belwo. But getting the current week sum of sales_amount  and amount not before Monday sum(sales_amount) and sum (amount).

```
select ISNULL(samt,0)samt, ISNULL(pamt,0)pamt,(ISNULL(samt,0)-ISNULL(pamt,0))prbal from
(
SELECT DATEPART(wk, s.Sale_Date)weekno,SUM(S.SALE_AMOUNT)samt FROM SALES S 
where  
 s.Sale_Date between '04/01/2016' and '03/31/2017' and
 S.sale_agent='SA1008'  
 And s.Sale_Date < DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,s.Sale_Date), 0)
 group by DATEPART(wk, s.Sale_Date)
 ) as a
full outer join
 (
 select DATEPART(wk, pa.Received_Date)weekno, sum(pa.amount)pamt
 from payment pa 
 where pa.Received_Date between '04/01/2016' and '03/31/2017' 
 AND pa.agent_Id ='SA1008' 
 and Pa.RECEIVED_DATE < DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,pa.Received_Date), 0)  
 group by DATEPART(wk, pa.Received_Date)
 ) as b
 on a.weekno=b.weekno
```

I want to show sum(sales_amount) from sales table and sum(amount) from payment table prior to every weekly Monday in financial year

Dummy Data

**sales**

```
    Sales_Id Sale_Agent     Sale_Date      Quantity Rate    Sale_Amount
      42409  SA1008    2016-03-30 00:00:00  25      87.00      4976.40
     42338   SA1008     2016-03-27 00:00:00 25      93.00      4073.40
     42287   SA1008    2016-03-25 00:00:00  30      95.00      6384.00
     42231   SA1008    2016-03-23 00:00:00  40      95.00      8987.00
     42149   SA1008    2016-03-20 00:00:00  40      98.00      9976.40
     42099   SA1008    2016-03-18 00:00:00  20      102.00     4549.20
```

**Payment**

```
   Payement_id  Agent_Id    Amount  Received_Date
     22615       SA1008     7000.00 2016-03-30 00:00:00
     22550       SA1008     2000.00 2016-03-26 00:00:00
     22529       SA1008     8000.00 2016-03-25 00:00:00
     22509       SA1008     5000.00 2016-03-23 00:00:00
    22443        SA1008     12500.00 2016-03-19 00:00:00
```

Expected Output:

```
weekno  samt    weekno  pamt    prbal
14      5580.00 NULL    NULL    5580.00
15      8464.00 NULL    NULL    8464.00
16      7272.60 NULL    NULL    7272.60
17      8820.00 NULL    NULL    8820.00
```

Samt(salesamt) and Pamt(payment amount) is  not giving proper output.
actually for weekno samt is 3193683.80 and Pamt is 3095708.00 but amt and pamt showing current week sum of sales amount and payment amount.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Comment: Can you show sample data and expected outcome?

Comment: We need both input data **and** expected outcome!

Comment: I changed the question.please help.